# Is it possible for an international medical graduate to take their residency and fellowship training in Singapore?

Tags: medicine, training, singapore

I am graduating medicine in 2 years time.  I am from Indonesia. I tried inquiring what the requirements are, but I have not been getting any straight answers thus far.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find anything about fellowship yet. But, about the residency training,

The [Singapore government agency](https://www.healthprofessionals.gov.sg/sab/specialist-training/general-information-training-programmes) says

> **Enrolment into Training Programmes**

> **...**
> Graduands from overseas must secure an offer of employment as a doctor from MOHH or a local healthcare institution before they are eligible to apply. **...**

For more details, please [contact them](https://www.healthprofessionals.gov.sg/sab/contact-info) directly.